# Fetch/XHR own files

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

My extension works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. I wanted to support edge too. However I cannot do a simple thing, I cannot `fetch`/`XHR` my own files! I even added `<all_urls>` to my `permissions` array in `manifest.json`, however I keep getting `TypeMismatchError` and in details it says "Permission Denied". Here is a screenshot:

[image: devtools screenshot]

Does anyone know if it is possible to fetch your own files in Edge? I need to specifically fetch the messages.json files in my `/_locales/*` folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which has been reported here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8546263/, you can use the workaround mentioned in the link or use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch`.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('test/test.js');
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Oooo, thank you very much! I didn't realize it was for all resources!

Comment: This should also be fixed in the Creators Update! Please file a bug at http://aka.ms/edge-issues if you still see this on versions of Edge 15.15063 or higher.